# Unable to parse XML of SOAP request to Dataset

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

Im busy writing a webservice that will accept a SOAP REQUEST of up to 5 tables worth of information.

This is what I have come up with as a valid SOAP REQUEST but I have removed 4 tables worth of XML for simplicity.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:EchoSoapRequest1>         
         <Route>  
            <Routecode>200906230000</RouteCode>
            <Date>23/06/2009</Date> 
            <type>1</type>
            <Depot_Code>'hh'</Depot_Code>
        </Route>
      </tem:EchoSoapRequest1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now, in my webservice, this is my attempt to read in the Route table to a dataset.Everything works up to this point and I can see the entire REQUEST in variable xmlSoapRequest.I need to strip out each table and save into their own dataset, so that I can manipulate and then just return a code back to the client program.

```
var xmlPayload =   xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("//Route");                  
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlPayload.innerxml);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:)

```
   var xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("//Route");        
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlPayload.OuterXml);

    XmlNodeReader xmlread = new XmlNodeReader(xmldoc);
    ds.ReadXml(xmlread);
```